# Laravel 4 How to show selected values in a dropdown menu by using the input::old() method?

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-4, jquery-select2

i am stuck with this.

I am using Laravel 4 and the select2 dropdown menu plugin.

I have a form where the user may choose one or more options from a dropwdown menu (the select2 plugin).

If the validation fails, then the user is returned again to the form. As for the correct inputs, i want the form to keep the selected values from the dropdown menus.

This is going well for one dropdown menu where the user must choose only one option. The code i've got is the following:

```
          <!-- Tipo de evento -->
          <div class="form-group <?php if($errors->has('tipo_evento')){echo "has-error";}else if(Input::old('tipo_evento')) echo "has-success"; ?>">
            <label for="tipo_evento" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <select multiple="" 
                class="select2 req_place form-control" placeholder="Elija" data-select-search="true"
                id="tipo_evento" name="tipo_evento" ><!-- required="" -->
                  @foreach($tipo_evento as $key1=>$datum)
                      @foreach($datum as $key2=>$value)
                          @if($key2=='id')
                              <option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('tipo_evento')==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>
                          @elseif($key2=='nombre')
                              {{$value}}</option>
                          @endif
                      @endforeach
                  @endforeach
              </select>
              @if($errors->has('tipo_evento'))
                  <p style="color: red;">{{$errors->first('tipo_evento')}}</p>
              @endif                      
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is going fine, when the form is returned (in case of errors) the selected option remains selected.

However, for the case of multiple select, that is to say, when the user may choose one or more options, nothing happens, none of the option remains selected.
Here is my code:

```
          <!-- Lugar en donde fue el evento -->
          <div class="form-group <?php if($errors->has('lugar')){echo "has-error";}else if(Input::old('lugar')) echo "has-success"; ?>">
            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Lugar(es)</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <select multiple="" 
                class="select2 req_place form-control" placeholder="Elija" data-select-search="true"
                id="lugar" name="lugar[]" ><!-- required="" -->
                  @foreach($lugares as $key1=>$datum)
                      @foreach($datum as $key2=>$value)
                          @if($key2=='id')
                              <option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('lugar[]')==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>
                          @elseif($key2=='lugar')
                              {{$value}}</option>
                          @endif
                      @endforeach
                  @endforeach
              </select>
              <p style="color:blue;">{{Input::old('lugar[]')}}</p>
              @if($errors->has('lugar'))
                  <p style="color: red;">{{$errors->first('lugar')}}</p>
              @endif                      
            </div>
          </div>
```

I have tried this:

```
<option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('lugar[$value]')==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>
```

And this:

```
<option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('lugar')==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>
```

And so on...

I have found a hint [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2951) but i am trying to find out how to put the variable a not a constant or name ...

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(Input::old('lugar.' . $key1)` or `(Input::old('lugar.' . $key2)`, I'm not really sure what you are doing there. If that doesnt help, could you show the var_dump of `Input::old('lugar')` and `$lugares`

Edit:

```
<!-- Lugar en donde fue el evento -->
<div class="form-group <?php if($errors->has('lugar')){echo "has-error";}else if(Input::old('lugar')) echo "has-success"; ?>">
    <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Lugar(es)</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select multiple class="select2 req_place form-control" placeholder="Elija" data-select-search="true" id="lugar" name="lugar[]" >
            @foreach($lugares as $key1=>$datum)
                @foreach($datum as $key2=>$value)
                    @if($key2=='id')
                        <option value="{{$value}}" @if(is_array(Input::old('lugar')) && in_array($value, Input::old('lugar'))){{' selected'}}@endif>
                            @elseif($key2=='lugar')
                                {{$value}}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <p style="color:blue;">{{Input::old('lugar[]')}}</p>
        @if($errors->has('lugar'))
            <p style="color: red;">{{$errors->first('lugar')}}</p>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show use the controller code or the output when you var_dump(Input::old('lugar')) or dd(Input::old('lugar'))

Comment: If select a value, then return to the form with the errors, i get the following: `Array
(
    [0] => 4
)` by using print_r() `print_r(Input::old('lugar'),true)` below the dropdown menu.

Comment: I get the following error: `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array`. However, if i use 0 like this: `<option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('lugar.0')==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>` It does work!!! BUT, if i want to use this for multiple select, if i try `<option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('lugar'.$key2)==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>` It does not work, the how would i use it for $variables???

Comment: You are forgetting about the "." `Input::old('lugar.'.$key2)` not `Input::old('lugar'.$key2)`

Comment: Yes, i have tried it `<option value="{{$value}}" {{ (Input::old('lugar.'.$key2)==$value) ? ' selected="" ' : ''}}>` but it does not work yet :/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
{{ Form::select('lugar[]', $tipo_evento, Input::old('lugar[]'), ['multiple' => true]) }}
```

No need to do a loop manually.

Comment: Here the input:old() returns all values as selected. How do i make the select to only display those values the user had chosen as selected?

Answer (score 0):

There is some unnecessary code here which can be cleaned up quite easily.

Build out your options array in your controller to save all the clutter and mess in your view.  That's not the best place to handle that.  In your controller, it might look like this...

```
$options = [];
foreach($lugares as $datum) {
    foreach($datum as $value) {
        $options[$value['id']] = $value['lugar'];
    }
}
```

And be sure to pass `$options` into your view.  Then your view becomes very easy!

```
{{ Form::select('lugar[]', $options, Input::old('lugar'), array('multiple' => true, 'class' => 'select2 req_place form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Elija', 'data-select-search' => 'true', 'id' => 'lugar')) }}
```

Comment: Okkei, it seems to work much better. However, the problem is that, if the form is returned, all the values appear to be selected. It'd be nice to show only those values (options) that the user had selected. How would i only display those values the user had chosen as selected??

Comment: That should be happening currently.  Somehow all the values are being inserted into `Input::old('lugar')`.  Can you `dd(Input::old('lugar'))` somewhere and see what's in there?

Comment: For example, if i choose one (which id=2), the array is the following: `Array
(
    [0] => 2
)` Then if option value equals 2, that item should be shown as selected.

Comment: Yeah, Laravel should be handling that for you when you pass in `Input::old('lugar')`.  It will look at everything in that array and make sure its all selected.

Comment: Yes, i am using `print_r(Input::old('lugar'),true)` below the dropdown menu ... i am trying to figure out what i am missing ...

Comment: Try removing some of the classes.  I wonder if the javascript is somehow selecting all the things or falsely showing them as selected when they are not.